# How to use ROS nodes (slam_gmapping) in Qt Creator GUI

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I’m really new to the ROS and I want to use ROS for my research studies. Basically I hope to use SLAM package in ROS.
Can anyone please be kind enough to give me A-Z instructions to use SLAM package first. Then I want to know how I use this in my own GUI created by Qt creator.
In order to use SLAM in ROS what kind of sensors must be used (LRF, Odometry data, IMU)

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172246/how-to-use-ros-nodes-(slam_gmapping)-in-qt-creator-gui/) by [TS](https://answers.ros.org/users/18731/ts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

[Gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) need's two topics which provide laser scanner and odometry . usually use lidar sensor for laser scanner . if you want to use only laser scanner you can use [Hector_Mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) .

for using  Qt Creator GUI in Ros please see this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12790/ros-qt-creator-gui/).

if you want to subscribe map or pose topic in your gui you can build one timer in your code and call  ros::spinOnce() every 10ms.

note: your gui use app.exec() and if you use ros::spin()  then your gui doesn't work .

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1